# curl returns correct result but hangs on LDAP

Tags: linux, curl, ldap, debian, rcurl

I faced a strange issue while querying LDAP Active Directory via curl: directly and via R wrapper - RCurl.

When I run RCurl under R session on Windows, my query is evaluated and result is returned immediately. Everything is fine.

When I do the same under R on Linux Debian, it hangs. So I've run the query via curl from the Linux command line. It turned out that the result is returned correctly (all information is correct), but curl is waiting for something. Only Ctrl+C can stop that.

My query:

```
 LDAP://x.x.x.x/dc=company,dc=com?userPrincipalName,msExchShadowGivenName,msExchShadowSn,sAMAccountName?sub?(&(objectCategory=person)(msExchShadowProxyAddresses=*some@email.com*))
```

My call:

```
curl -u user@domain:pwd "ldap://ip/......"
```

Why the query on Windows is evaluated successfully and curl returns results immediately, while the same query on Linux makes curl hanged? Should I set some additional options?

Thanks in advance.

--EDIT
This may be important: Debian is running under Hyper-V virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Set `LDAPREFERRALS=off`, like this example that looks up the email of the user account named `usertobelookedup`:

```
LDAPREFERRALS=off curl --user "cn=ldapuser":'ldappassword' ldap://serveraddress:389/DC=mycompany,DC=com?mail?sub?"(sAMAccountName=usertobelookedup)"
```

Reference: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/622